# What is a more efficent way to populate new variables based on other variable results in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using Pandas to populate 6 new variables with values that are conditional to other data variables. The entire dataset consists of about 700,000 rows and 14 variables (columns) including my newly added ones.

My first approach was to use `itertuples()`, mainly down to experience being minimal here. This clocked around 9600 seconds.

I've managed to get this more efficient (~3500 seconds) by using apply().  Here is an example of one of the new variables.

```py
housing_df = utils.make_data_frame("data/source_data/housing_with_child.dta", "stata")

""" Populate new variables """
# setup new variables
housing_df["hh_n"] = ""
housing_df["bio_d"] = ""
housing_df["step_d"] = ""
housing_df["child_d"] = ""
housing_df["both_bio"] = ""
housing_df["hhtype"] = ""
housing_df["step"] = ""


# hh_n
def hh_n(row):
    df = housing_df.loc[
            (housing_df["pidp"] == row["pidp"]) & (housing_df["wave"] == row["wave"])
        ]
    return str(len(df.index) + 1)

housing_df["hh_n"] = housing_df.apply(hh_n, axis=1)
```

Each new variable follows the same pattern and needs to do the following:

```html
For each row
Get some of the rows existing data (eg pipd and wave)
Find rows in the whole data frame which have the same values (pidp and wave) and put these in a new dataframe
Count the rows we found in the new dataframe
Return the count value for the new variable (hh_n)
```

Here is a small example of the output data:

[image: eg of output]

In case it's relevant, here is my method for creating a dataframe from the stata file in the first line:

```py
# Method that returns data frame from stata file or csv
def make_data_frame(data, type):
    if type is "stata":
        reader = pd.read_stata(data, chunksize=100000)
    if type is "csv":
        reader = pd.read_csv(data, chunksize=100000)
    df = pd.DataFrame()

    for itm in reader:
        df = df.append(itm)
    return df
```

Here is an example of the first 50 rows of data

```py
{'index': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10, 11: 11, 12: 12, 13: 13, 14: 14, 15: 15, 16: 16, 17: 17, 18: 18, 19: 19, 20: 20, 21: 21, 22: 22, 23: 23, 24: 24, 25: 25, 26: 26, 27: 27, 28: 28, 29: 29, 30: 30, 31: 31, 32: 32, 33: 33, 34: 34, 35: 35, 36: 36, 37: 37, 38: 38, 39: 39, 40: 40, 41: 41, 42: 42, 43: 43, 44: 44, 45: 45, 46: 46, 47: 47, 48: 48, 49: 49, 50: 50, 51: 51, 52: 52, 53: 53, 54: 54, 55: 55, 56: 56, 57: 57, 58: 58, 59: 59, 60: 60, 61: 61, 62: 62, 63: 63, 64: 64, 65: 65, 66: 66, 67: 67, 68: 68, 69: 69, 70: 70, 71: 71, 72: 72, 73: 73, 74: 74, 75: 75, 76: 76, 77: 77, 78: 78, 79: 79, 80: 80, 81: 81, 82: 82, 83: 83, 84: 84, 85: 85, 86: 86, 87: 87, 88: 88, 89: 89, 90: 90, 91: 91, 92: 92, 93: 93, 94: 94, 95: 95, 96: 96, 97: 97, 98: 98, 99: 99}, 'pidp': {0: 1367, 1: 2051, 2: 2727, 3: 2727, 4: 2727, 5: 2727, 6: 2727, 7: 3407, 8: 3407, 9: 3407, 10: 3407, 11: 3407, 12: 3407, 13: 3407, 14: 3407, 15: 3407, 16: 3407, 17: 3407, 18: 3407, 19: 3407, 20: 3407, 21: 3407, 22: 3407, 23: 3407, 24: 3407, 25: 3407, 26: 3407, 27: 3407, 28: 3407, 29: 4091, 30: 4091, 31: 4091, 32: 4091, 33: 4091, 34: 4091, 35: 4091, 36: 4091, 37: 4767, 38: 4767, 39: 4767, 40: 4767, 41: 4767, 42: 4767, 43: 5451, 44: 5451, 45: 5451, 46: 5451, 47: 5451, 48: 5451, 49: 6135, 50: 6135, 51: 6135, 52: 6135, 53: 6135, 54: 6807, 55: 6807, 56: 6844, 57: 6844, 58: 6844, 59: 6844, 60: 6844, 61: 6844, 62: 6844, 63: 6844, 64: 6844, 65: 6844, 66: 6844, 67: 6844, 68: 6844, 69: 6844, 70: 6844, 71: 6844, 72: 6844, 73: 6844, 74: 6844, 75: 6844, 76: 6844, 77: 6844, 78: 6844, 79: 6844, 80: 6844, 81: 6844, 82: 6844, 83: 6844, 84: 6844, 85: 6844, 86: 6844, 87: 6844, 88: 6844, 89: 6844, 90: 6844, 91: 6844, 92: 6844, 93: 6844, 94: 6844, 95: 6844, 96: 6844, 97: 6844, 98: 6844, 99: 6844}, 'hidp': {0: 20402, 1: 20402, 2: 5799043, 3: 60159608, 4: 45594010, 5: 53475212, 6: 15449616, 7: 102002, 8: 102002, 9: 30559202, 10: 30559202, 11: 6351204, 12: 6351204, 13: 2590808, 14: 13610, 15: 6812, 16: 13614, 17: 20416, 18: 21902818, 19: 36407220, 20: 36407220, 21: 20424, 22: 20424, 23: 20426, 24: 20426, 25: 9010028, 26: 9010028, 27: 18856430, 28: 18856430, 29: 136002, 30: 136002, 31: 30566002, 32: 30566002, 33: 6358004, 34: 6358004, 35: 20406, 36: 20406, 37: 210802, 38: 210802, 39: 30579602, 40: 30579602, 41: 30579602, 42: 6371604, 43: 210802, 44: 210802, 45: 30579602, 46: 30579602, 47: 30579602, 48: 6371604, 49: 210802, 50: 210802, 51: 30579602, 52: 30579602, 53: 30579602, 54: 285602, 55: 30593202, 56: 37073606, 57: 37073606, 58: 37073606, 59: 37073606, 60: 37073606, 61: 12580008, 62: 12580008, 63: 12580008, 64: 12580008, 65: 12580008, 66: 56052408, 67: 56052408, 68: 56052408, 69: 56052408, 70: 56052408, 71: 38848410, 72: 38848410, 73: 38848410, 74: 38848410, 75: 38848410, 76: 50014012, 77: 50014012, 78: 50014012, 79: 5467216, 80: 5467216, 81: 5467216, 82: 25547618, 83: 25547618, 84: 25547618, 85: 38610420, 86: 38610420, 87: 38610420, 88: 5025224, 89: 5025224, 90: 5025224, 91: 4637626, 92: 4637626, 93: 4637626, 94: 12784028, 95: 12784028, 96: 12784028, 97: 21719230, 98: 21719230, 99: 21719230}, 'apidp': {0: 2051, 1: 1367, 2: 752052125, 3: 752052125, 4: 752052125, 5: 752052125, 6: 752052125, 7: 545740805, 8: 612001365, 9: 545740805, 10: 612001365, 11: 545740805, 12: 612001365, 13: 612001365, 14: 612001365, 15: 612001365, 16: 612001365, 17: 612001365, 18: 612001365, 19: 612001365, 20: 612001369, 21: 612001365, 22: 612001369, 23: 612001365, 24: 612001369, 25: 612001365, 26: 612001369, 27: 612001365, 28: 612001369, 29: 68002045, 30: 68002049, 31: 68002045, 32: 68002049, 33: 68002045, 34: 68002049, 35: 68002045, 36: 68002049, 37: 5451, 38: 6135, 39: 5451, 40: 6135, 41: 5298579, 42: 5451, 43: 4767, 44: 6135, 45: 4767, 46: 6135, 47: 5298579, 48: 4767, 49: 4767, 50: 5451, 51: 4767, 52: 5451, 53: 5298579, 54: 4885131, 55: 4885131, 56: 13644, 57: 748469885, 58: 748469889, 59: 749992405, 60: 749992409, 61: 13644, 62: 748469885, 63: 748469889, 64: 749992405, 65: 749992409, 66: 13644, 67: 748469885, 68: 748469889, 69: 749992405, 70: 749992409, 71: 13644, 72: 748469885, 73: 748469889, 74: 749992405, 75: 749992409, 76: 13644, 77: 748469885, 78: 748469889, 79: 13644, 80: 748469885, 81: 748469889, 82: 13644, 83: 748469885, 84: 748469889, 85: 13644, 86: 748469885, 87: 748469889, 88: 13644, 89: 748469885, 90: 748469889, 91: 13644, 92: 748469885, 93: 748469889, 94: 13644, 95: 748469885, 96: 748469889, 97: 13644, 98: 748469885, 99: 748469889}, 'wave': {0: 2.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 8.0, 4: 9.0, 5: 10.0, 6: 11.0, 7: 2.0, 8: 2.0, 9: 3.0, 10: 3.0, 11: 4.0, 12: 4.0, 13: 7.0, 14: 8.0, 15: 9.0, 16: 10.0, 17: 11.0, 18: 12.0, 19: 13.0, 20: 13.0, 21: 14.0, 22: 14.0, 23: 15.0, 24: 15.0, 25: 16.0, 26: 16.0, 27: 17.0, 28: 17.0, 29: 2.0, 30: 2.0, 31: 3.0, 32: 3.0, 33: 4.0, 34: 4.0, 35: 5.0, 36: 5.0, 37: 2.0, 38: 2.0, 39: 3.0, 40: 3.0, 41: 3.0, 42: 4.0, 43: 2.0, 44: 2.0, 45: 3.0, 46: 3.0, 47: 3.0, 48: 4.0, 49: 2.0, 50: 2.0, 51: 3.0, 52: 3.0, 53: 3.0, 54: 2.0, 55: 3.0, 56: 6.0, 57: 6.0, 58: 6.0, 59: 6.0, 60: 6.0, 61: 7.0, 62: 7.0, 63: 7.0, 64: 7.0, 65: 7.0, 66: 8.0, 67: 8.0, 68: 8.0, 69: 8.0, 70: 8.0, 71: 9.0, 72: 9.0, 73: 9.0, 74: 9.0, 75: 9.0, 76: 10.0, 77: 10.0, 78: 10.0, 79: 11.0, 80: 11.0, 81: 11.0, 82: 12.0, 83: 12.0, 84: 12.0, 85: 13.0, 86: 13.0, 87: 13.0, 88: 14.0, 89: 14.0, 90: 14.0, 91: 15.0, 92: 15.0, 93: 15.0, 94: 16.0, 95: 16.0, 96: 16.0, 97: 17.0, 98: 17.0, 99: 17.0}, 'rel': {0: 'unrelated sharer', 1: 'unrelated sharer', 2: 'natural child', 3: 'natural child', 4: 'natural child', 5: 'natural child', 6: 'natural child', 7: 'lawful spouse', 8: 'natural child', 9: 'lawful spouse', 10: 'natural child', 11: 'lawful spouse', 12: 'natural child', 13: 'natural child', 14: 'natural child', 15: 'natural child', 16: 'natural child', 17: 'natural child', 18: 'natural child', 19: 'natural child', 20: 'daughter/son-in-law', 21: 'natural child', 22: 'daughter/son-in-law', 23: 'natural child', 24: 'daughter/son-in-law', 25: 'natural child', 26: 'daughter/son-in-law', 27: 'natural child', 28: 'daughter/son-in-law', 29: 'lawful spouse', 30: 'natural child', 31: 'lawful spouse', 32: 'natural child', 33: 'lawful spouse', 34: 'natural child', 35: 'lawful spouse', 36: 'natural child', 37: 'unrelated sharer', 38: 'natural child', 39: 'other', 40: 'natural child', 41: 'daughter/son-in-law', 42: 'other', 43: 'unrelated sharer', 44: 'natural child', 45: 'other', 46: 'natural child', 47: 'daughter/son-in-law', 48: 'other', 49: 'natural parent', 50: 'natural parent', 51: 'natural parent', 52: 'natural parent', 53: 'lawful spouse', 54: 'natural brother/sister', 55: 'natural brother/sister', 56: 'natural child', 57: 'lawful spouse', 58: 'natural child', 59: 'mother/father-in-law', 60: 'mother/father-in-law', 61: 'natural child', 62: 'lawful spouse', 63: 'natural child', 64: 'mother/father-in-law', 65: 'mother/father-in-law', 66: 'natural child', 67: 'lawful spouse', 68: 'natural child', 69: 'mother/father-in-law', 70: 'mother/father-in-law', 71: 'natural child', 72: 'lawful spouse', 73: 'natural child', 74: 'mother/father-in-law', 75: 'mother/father-in-law', 76: 'natural child', 77: 'lawful spouse', 78: 'natural child', 79: 'natural child', 80: 'lawful spouse', 81: 'natural child', 82: 'natural child', 83: 'lawful spouse', 84: 'natural child', 85: 'natural child', 86: 'lawful spouse', 87: 'natural child', 88: 'natural child', 89: 'lawful spouse', 90: 'natural child', 91: 'natural child', 92: 'lawful spouse', 93: 'natural child', 94: 'natural child', 95: 'lawful spouse', 96: 'natural child', 97: 'natural child', 98: 'lawful spouse', 99: 'natural child'}, 'is_child': {0: '', 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '', 6: '', 7: '', 8: '1', 9: '', 10: '1', 11: '', 12: '1', 13: '', 14: '', 15: '', 16: '', 17: '', 18: '', 19: '', 20: '', 21: '', 22: '', 23: '', 24: '', 25: '', 26: '', 27: '', 28: '', 29: '', 30: '1', 31: '', 32: '1', 33: '', 34: '1', 35: '', 36: '', 37: '', 38: '', 39: '', 40: '', 41: '', 42: '', 43: '', 44: '', 45: '', 46: '', 47: '', 48: '', 49: '', 50: '', 51: '', 52: '', 53: '', 54: '', 55: '', 56: '1', 57: '', 58: '1', 59: '', 60: '', 61: '1', 62: '', 63: '1', 64: '', 65: '', 66: '1', 67: '', 68: '1', 69: '', 70: '', 71: '1', 72: '', 73: '1', 74: '', 75: '', 76: '1', 77: '', 78: '1', 79: '1', 80: '', 81: '1', 82: '1', 83: '', 84: '1', 85: '1', 86: '', 87: '1', 88: '1', 89: '', 90: '1', 91: '1', 92: '', 93: '1', 94: '1', 95: '', 96: '1', 97: '1', 98: '', 99: '1'}, 'hh_n': {0: '', 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '', 6: '', 7: '', 8: '', 9: '', 10: '', 11: '', 12: '', 13: '', 14: '', 15: '', 16: '', 17: '', 18: '', 19: '', 20: '', 21: '', 22: '', 23: '', 24: '', 25: '', 26: '', 27: '', 28: '', 29: '', 30: '', 31: '', 32: '', 33: '', 34: '', 35: '', 36: '', 37: '', 38: '', 39: '', 40: '', 41: '', 42: '', 43: '', 44: '', 45: '', 46: '', 47: '', 48: '', 49: '', 50: '', 51: '', 52: '', 53: '', 54: '', 55: '', 56: '', 57: '', 58: '', 59: '', 60: '', 61: '', 62: '', 63: '', 64: '', 65: '', 66: '', 67: '', 68: '', 69: '', 70: '', 71: '', 72: '', 73: '', 74: '', 75: '', 76: '', 77: '', 78: '', 79: '', 80: '', 81: '', 82: '', 83: '', 84: '', 85: '', 86: '', 87: '', 88: '', 89: '', 90: '', 91: '', 92: '', 93: '', 94: '', 95: '', 96: '', 97: '', 98: '', 99: ''}, 'bio_d': {0: '', 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '', 6: '', 7: '', 8: '', 9: '', 10: '', 11: '', 12: '', 13: '', 14: '', 15: '', 16: '', 17: '', 18: '', 19: '', 20: '', 21: '', 22: '', 23: '', 24: '', 25: '', 26: '', 27: '', 28: '', 29: '', 30: '', 31: '', 32: '', 33: '', 34: '', 35: '', 36: '', 37: '', 38: '', 39: '', 40: '', 41: '', 42: '', 43: '', 44: '', 45: '', 46: '', 47: '', 48: '', 49: '', 50: '', 51: '', 52: '', 53: '', 54: '', 55: '', 56: '', 57: '', 58: '', 59: '', 60: '', 61: '', 62: '', 63: '', 64: '', 65: '', 66: '', 67: '', 68: '', 69: '', 70: '', 71: '', 72: '', 73: '', 74: '', 75: '', 76: '', 77: '', 78: '', 79: '', 80: '', 81: '', 82: '', 83: '', 84: '', 85: '', 86: '', 87: '', 88: '', 89: '', 90: '', 91: '', 92: '', 93: '', 94: '', 95: '', 96: '', 97: '', 98: '', 99: ''}, 'step_d': {0: '', 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '', 6: '', 7: '', 8: '', 9: '', 10: '', 11: '', 12: '', 13: '', 14: '', 15: '', 16: '', 17: '', 18: '', 19: '', 20: '', 21: '', 22: '', 23: '', 24: '', 25: '', 26: '', 27: '', 28: '', 29: '', 30: '', 31: '', 32: '', 33: '', 34: '', 35: '', 36: '', 37: '', 38: '', 39: '', 40: '', 41: '', 42: '', 43: '', 44: '', 45: '', 46: '', 47: '', 48: '', 49: '', 50: '', 51: '', 52: '', 53: '', 54: '', 55: '', 56: '', 57: '', 58: '', 59: '', 60: '', 61: '', 62: '', 63: '', 64: '', 65: '', 66: '', 67: '', 68: '', 69: '', 70: '', 71: '', 72: '', 73: '', 74: '', 75: '', 76: '', 77: '', 78: '', 79: '', 80: '', 81: '', 82: '', 83: '', 84: '', 85: '', 86: '', 87: '', 88: '', 89: '', 90: '', 91: '', 92: '', 93: '', 94: '', 95: '', 96: '', 97: '', 98: '', 99: ''}, 'child_d': {0: '', 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '', 6: '', 7: '', 8: '', 9: '', 10: '', 11: '', 12: '', 13: '', 14: '', 15: '', 16: '', 17: '', 18: '', 19: '', 20: '', 21: '', 22: '', 23: '', 24: '', 25: '', 26: '', 27: '', 28: '', 29: '', 30: '', 31: '', 32: '', 33: '', 34: '', 35: '', 36: '', 37: '', 38: '', 39: '', 40: '', 41: '', 42: '', 43: '', 44: '', 45: '', 46: '', 47: '', 48: '', 49: '', 50: '', 51: '', 52: '', 53: '', 54: '', 55: '', 56: '', 57: '', 58: '', 59: '', 60: '', 61: '', 62: '', 63: '', 64: '', 65: '', 66: '', 67: '', 68: '', 69: '', 70: '', 71: '', 72: '', 73: '', 74: '', 75: '', 76: '', 77: '', 78: '', 79: '', 80: '', 81: '', 82: '', 83: '', 84: '', 85: '', 86: '', 87: '', 88: '', 89: '', 90: '', 91: '', 92: '', 93: '', 94: '', 95: '', 96: '', 97: '', 98: '', 99: ''}, 'both_bio': {0: '', 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '', 6: '', 7: '', 8: '', 9: '', 10: '', 11: '', 12: '', 13: '', 14: '', 15: '', 16: '', 17: '', 18: '', 19: '', 20: '', 21: '', 22: '', 23: '', 24: '', 25: '', 26: '', 27: '', 28: '', 29: '', 30: '', 31: '', 32: '', 33: '', 34: '', 35: '', 36: '', 37: '', 38: '', 39: '', 40: '', 41: '', 42: '', 43: '', 44: '', 45: '', 46: '', 47: '', 48: '', 49: '', 50: '', 51: '', 52: '', 53: '', 54: '', 55: '', 56: '', 57: '', 58: '', 59: '', 60: '', 61: '', 62: '', 63: '', 64: '', 65: '', 66: '', 67: '', 68: '', 69: '', 70: '', 71: '', 72: '', 73: '', 74: '', 75: '', 76: '', 77: '', 78: '', 79: '', 80: '', 81: '', 82: '', 83: '', 84: '', 85: '', 86: '', 87: '', 88: '', 89: '', 90: '', 91: '', 92: '', 93: '', 94: '', 95: '', 96: '', 97: '', 98: '', 99: ''}, 'hhtype': {0: '', 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '', 6: '', 7: '', 8: '', 9: '', 10: '', 11: '', 12: '', 13: '', 14: '', 15: '', 16: '', 17: '', 18: '', 19: '', 20: '', 21: '', 22: '', 23: '', 24: '', 25: '', 26: '', 27: '', 28: '', 29: '', 30: '', 31: '', 32: '', 33: '', 34: '', 35: '', 36: '', 37: '', 38: '', 39: '', 40: '', 41: '', 42: '', 43: '', 44: '', 45: '', 46: '', 47: '', 48: '', 49: '', 50: '', 51: '', 52: '', 53: '', 54: '', 55: '', 56: '', 57: '', 58: '', 59: '', 60: '', 61: '', 62: '', 63: '', 64: '', 65: '', 66: '', 67: '', 68: '', 69: '', 70: '', 71: '', 72: '', 73: '', 74: '', 75: '', 76: '', 77: '', 78: '', 79: '', 80: '', 81: '', 82: '', 83: '', 84: '', 85: '', 86: '', 87: '', 88: '', 89: '', 90: '', 91: '', 92: '', 93: '', 94: '', 95: '', 96: '', 97: '', 98: '', 99: ''}, 'step': {0: '', 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '', 6: '', 7: '', 8: '', 9: '', 10: '', 11: '', 12: '', 13: '', 14: '', 15: '', 16: '', 17: '', 18: '', 19: '', 20: '', 21: '', 22: '', 23: '', 24: '', 25: '', 26: '', 27: '', 28: '', 29: '', 30: '', 31: '', 32: '', 33: '', 34: '', 35: '', 36: '', 37: '', 38: '', 39: '', 40: '', 41: '', 42: '', 43: '', 44: '', 45: '', 46: '', 47: '', 48: '', 49: '', 50: '', 51: '', 52: '', 53: '', 54: '', 55: '', 56: '', 57: '', 58: '', 59: '', 60: '', 61: '', 62: '', 63: '', 64: '', 65: '', 66: '', 67: '', 68: '', 69: '', 70: '', 71: '', 72: '', 73: '', 74: '', 75: '', 76: '', 77: '', 78: '', 79: '', 80: '', 81: '', 82: '', 83: '', 84: '', 85: '', 86: '', 87: '', 88: '', 89: '', 90: '', 91: '', 92: '', 93: '', 94: '', 95: '', 96: '', 97: '', 98: '', 99: ''}}
```

[image: First 50 rows]

Comment: Could you add some example data which we can use to reproduce your tried solution, but also reproduce an answer for you. Also adding an expected output clears things up a lot.

Comment: Thanks @Erfan, I've given the first 50 rows as an example of the data. I don't really have an expectation as such, if anything I was expecting `apply()` to work a lot more efficiently than `itertuples()` which it does but it's still not efficient enough for the entire dataset. At an estimate using my above code, it would be about 8 hours in total so I'm expecting this to be a lot lower.

Comment: We cannot copy a picture. Use copy and paste to add the data. Second, with expected output I mean what you would like to see as final output based on the example data you gave. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) on how to make a good pandas question.

Comment: Might be too good to be true, but do you want: `df.groupby(['pipd', 'wave'])['pipd'].size()`?

Comment: Thanks, I've added a dict of the data.

Comment: `housing_df["hh_n"] = housing_df.groupby(['pidp', 'wave']).transform('count')`?

Comment: I did a long (deleted) merge answer only to find out @Parfait is the correct answer. Using .transform on 10,000,000 rows takes .59 seconds.

Comment: Yep, `housing_df["hh_n"] = housing_df.groupby(['pidp', 'wave']).transform('count')` is WAY faster. @parfait if you want to add this as an answer I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to pass conditions using this method? eg `housing_df["hh_n"] = housing_df.groupby(['pidp', 'wave', 'rel' == 1]).transform('count')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated, consider [`groupby().transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation) for any groupwise, in-line aggregation to assign a new column to current data frame. Since OP's needs is essentially counting (i.e., returning the length of index or number of rows from a logical condition), specify the `count` aggregate explicitly.

Therefore, the below `.apply()` (hidden loop that builds a helper data frame with each iteration)

```
def hh_n(row):
    # BOOLEAN INDEXING + LEN()
    df = housing_df.loc[
                (housing_df["pidp"] == row["pidp"]) & (housing_df["wave"] == row["wave"])
            ]
    return str(len(df.index) + 1)

housing_df["hh_n"] = housing_df.apply(hh_n, axis=1)
```

Can be adjusted as:

```
housing_df["hh_n"] = housing_df.groupby(['pidp', 'wave']).transform('count') + 1
```